# How to parse addresses from a page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to implement a simple search engine and at the first stage I collect data from the page, which will then be searched. However, trying to take links to each news item from the page, I get an error. The error sounds like this:

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.zrg74.ruhttp', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //zrg74.ru/sport/item/26982-dorogoj-v-bolshoj-hokkej-v-zlatouste-namereny-sozdat-otdelnuju-sekciju-dlja-podgotovki-vratarej.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000174B78FCBC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Here is a code snippet. It has a function get_page_text(), which gets the source of the page in the form in which it is:

```
...
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
        page_text = response.text
        return page_text
...
```

The URL processing code is as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text)
posts_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jeg_post_excerpt'}) 
for p in posts_list:
    lnk = p.find('a').attrs['href']
    title = re.sub('[^А-ЯЁа-яё0-9\s]', ' ', p.text)
    title = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ', title)
    page_url = 'http://www.zrg74.ru' + lnk
    clean_path = '/'.join([d for d in page_url.split('/')[2:] if len(d) > 0])

    page_text = get_page_text(page_url, USER_AGENT)
    if page_text is None:
        continue
    dir_path = 'data/raw_pages/' + '/'.join(clean_path.split('/')[:-1])
    makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True) 
    with open(dir_path + '/' + clean_path.split('/')[-1] + '.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(page_text)
```

The result I need at this stage is like this:

```
{'http://zrg74.ru/obshhestvo/item/26959-rabota-ne-dlja-galochki-zlatoustovec-povedal-o-njuansah-raboty-perepischika.html',
 'http://zrg74.ru/obshhestvo/item/26954-vzjalis-vmeste-dve-semi-iz-zlatousta-prinjali-uchastie-v-oblastnom-festivale-dlja-zameshhajushhih-semej.html'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this before. Usually, what worked for me was disconnecting my WiFi router, waiting a few seconds, and then reconnecting.

Try disabling your internet connection for a while and then enable it again.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far without result. It didn't help

Comment: As a result, I removed the code check with regular expressions and got rid of the page_url variable, replacing it further with lnk. It seems that it turned out to create directories, but, unfortunately, they are still empty. Couldn't parse addresses